# How do I add a custom app icon for AppleScript app?

Tags: macos, applescript, icon

I have my own AppleScript app. How would I add a custom App icon to it?

**EDIT:**

The only solution that has worked for me is pasting the image into the existing icon in Finder.

Comment: This has been covered many times before. Google is your friend! You can also have a look at: [Create custom icons for files or folders on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-custom-icons-files-folders-mac-mchlp2313/mac)

Comment: How do I close the question?

Comment: Todd, RE: "How do I close the question?" What do you mean by that? What is it you're wanting to do? Users do not have the direct ability to _close_ a question. That is done by users that have enough reputation to vote to close a question or moderators can directly close a question for the right reasons. Typically, questions only get closed for cause and the vast majority of questions remain open. By the way, in the context of Ask Different, closing a post means it cannot receive any (other) answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting from http://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_macOS#Create_a_launcher_app_with_AppleScript

> To change the application icon
>
> Open [image link] in a web browser, right-click and select "copy image".
>
> Select "Octave.app" in the Finder, then press command-i to bring up
> the file info dialog.
>
> In the file info dialog, select the icon (in the
> top left) and press command-v to paste the Octave icon over it.

Answer (score 1):

From the Finder. Right click on your Application and go to "Show Package Contents". The app will open up like a folder, navigate down to Contents/Resources/. In the Resources folder there is an .icns file. Replace that file with your custom icon (it will need to be formatted as an .icns file, not just a jpeg or png). I believe it needs to have the same name as the original file (so if it was droplet.icns, that is what you should name your replacement .icns file). Now you can close the folder, and do a get info on the App. You should now see the replacement icon for the App.

If it doesn't show up in the finder with the App, while in the Get Info page, select the icon in the upper left hand corner, copy it and paste it, that should update the finder icon with the new icon.